# Tokio / Tonic - How to fix this error: `self` has lifetime `'life0` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

I'm building a gRPC server using Rust and tonic and having some issues with a function that returns the stream. So far, the only examples I've seen conveniently create the tx and rx channels within the function - but this isn't a lot of help if you need to receive data from some other part of the application. I have the following code, but I'm getting an error.

**Code**

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream;
use tonic::transport::Server;
use tonic::{Request, Response, Status};use resourcemanager::{LineRequest, LineResponse, Position};
use resourcemanager::resource_manager_server::{ResourceManager, ResourceManagerServer};

pub mod resourcemanager {
    tonic::include_proto!("resourcemanager");
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ResourceManagerService {
    linear_rx: mpsc::Receiver<Position>,
    linear_tx: mpsc::Sender<Position>
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl ResourceManager for ResourceManagerService {
    async fn draw_line(&self, request: Request<LineRequest>) -> Result<Response<LineResponse>, Status> {
        Ok(Response::new(LineResponse::default()))
    }

    type StreamLinearMotorMovementStream = ReceiverStream<Result<Position, Status>>;

    async fn stream_linear_motor_movement(
        &self,
        request: Request<()>
    ) -> Result<Response<Self::StreamLinearMotorMovementStream>, Status> {
        println!("Streaming motor movements");
        let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            while let Some(received) = self.linear_rx.recv().await {
                tx.send(Ok(received.clone())).await.unwrap();
            }
        });

       Ok(Response::new(ReceiverStream::new(rx)))
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0759]: `self` has lifetime `'life0` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> src/main.rs:30:10
    |
30  |         &self,
    |          ^^^^ this data with lifetime `'life0`...
...
36  |         tokio::spawn(async move {
    |         ------------ ...is used and required to live as long as `'static` here
    |
note: `'static` lifetime requirement introduced by this bound
   --> /Users/xxxxxxxx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.18.2/src/task/spawn.rs:127:28
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                            ^^^^^^^
```

This error is shown underneath `&self` in:

```
async fn stream_linear_motor_movement(
        &self,
        request: Request<()>
    )
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the entire error message

Comment: Apologies. Thought I had. Edited includes full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message basically says it all. Abbreviated:

```rust
async fn stream_linear_motor_movement(&self) {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(received) = self.linear_rx.recv().await {}
    });
}
```

The fragment `self.linear_rx.recv().await` inside the newly spawned task forces the compiler to move `self` into that closure, so the closure can access `self.linear_rx`. However, as the new task *could* run forever, it requires its captured context to have a lifetime of `'static`, while `&self` has a limited, possibly shorter than `'static`, lifetime of `life0` (whatever that turns out to be). What that means is that you can't access `self` (or anything derived from it) from within the newly spawned task, because there is no guarantee that it will be around while the task is executing.

What you can do is to move `linear_rx` in `ResourceManagerService` into an `Arc`, `.clone()` that `Arc` in `stream_linear_motor_movement` and move that clone into the closure. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can also move `linear_rx` into an `Option` and `.take()` that `Option` in `stream_linear_motor_movement`, leaving `None` in its place. In both cases, you transfer an owned object into the newly spawned task, which has no lifetime shorter than `'static`. Notice that `Arc` would allow one to call `stream_linear_motor_movement` many times, while `Option` would only allow one to call it exactly once (because `linear_rx` is moved away on the first call).

Comment: Oh man, thank you! Using `Arc` and `.clone()` seems to have worked. I thought I'd tried this option, but apparently not. I will mark as correct as soon as I can verify it works, but I really appreciate the detailed answer!